# 'Attaching' divs to either side of fluid content (diagram inside...)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out the best way to attach two fixed width divs to a fluid center div. I've searched around for an answer to this problem but most people require a 3 column layout to fill the entire width of the screen, whereas I would like a variable amount of whitespace either side.

The intention is that the fluid div will wrap around images scaled to a fixed height but variable width.

Ideally if the edge of the screen is reached the two fixed divs wont go any further. Could this be done with pure css/a framework or is it easier to use javascript? I'm using node.js server-side if it helps.

Right now I'm using inline-block as a way to make it work, but it seems buggy when using percentage widths. It doesn't resize correctly the until page is refreshed, so I was hoping there was a better way.

[image: Image: two fixed divs 'attached' either side of a fluid div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the width coming from? [edit] added offsetWidth.
Here is a javascript approach -- I included an equal-heights routine.
It has the max-width check.  The code is commented.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
*        { outline:1px dotted #000; } /* all things */
body     { padding:0; border:0; margin:0; }
#bodyid  { }
#header, #footer { background:#eee; clear:both; }
#middle3 { background:#fee; clear:both; margin:auto; }
#fixedl  { background:#efe; float:left; width:50px; }
#fluid1  { background:#eef; float:left; }
#fixedr  { background:#efe; float:left; width:50px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1() { // process center 3 cols
  var wfluid1 = document.getElementById("fluid1").offsetWidth;
  var wfixedl = wfixedr = 50; // are fixed
  var wfluid1 = Math.min(wfluid1, screen.width - wfixedl - wfixedr); // max
  var wmiddle3 = wfixedl + wfluid1 + wfixedr;
  document.getElementById("middle3").style.width = wmiddle3 + "px";
  document.getElementById("fluid1").style.width = wfluid1 + "px";
  colsequal(new Array("fixedl", "fluid1", "fixedr")); // equal heights
  }
function colsequal(v1) { // makes column heights equal
  var h = document.getElementById(v1[0]).offsetHeight;
  for (i=1; i<v1.length; i++) { // get maximum height
    h = Math.max(h, document.getElementById(v1[i]).offsetHeight); }
  for (i=0; i<v1.length; i++) { // make all maximum
    document.getElementById(v1[i]).style.height = h + "px"; } 
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="f1();">
<div id="bodyid">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="middle3">
<div id="fixedl">Fixed<br />1</div>
<div id="fluid1">Fluid<br />1<br />2<br />3</div>
<div id="fixedr">Fixed<br />1<br />2</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div><!-- bodyid -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The width of the fluid div would be based on the width of the scaled image, which in turn would be derived from its fixed height and aspect ratio. 
Thanks for the javascript approach, looks like it solves the page boundaries problem :]

Answer (score 3):

Center the div containing fluid and fixed elements and, then `float:left` them.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2utM4/4/

Comment: Great simpler than I thought, +1 for pic